# Escape / encode double quotes in string before sending via post request

Tags: android, json

I'm sending string below from Android to web service using volley request

params.put("data", objData.toString());

objData.toString() -->

```
{"report_time":1413876429,"device_id":"13d404d1b3a38ffc","ads_info":"[{\"play_count\":\"26\",\"ad_id\":\"21\"},{\"play_count\":\"58\",\"ad_id\":\"37\"},{\"play_count\":\"14\",\"ad_id\":\"40\"}]"}
```

Server not accepting it due the `\"`

How to remove \ keeping the json correct ""

Comment: What is objData's type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the web service correctly.

Possibly the service expects to see a JSON array instead of a string containing JSON. Assuming `params` is a `JSONObject` and `objData` is a `JSONArray`, use `params.put("data", objData)` instead of the `toString()` version you have now.

Comment: This was the problem yes.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the double quotes with backslashes is the only way to do this in java.
One other option would be to put the String into some kind of text file that you would then read at runtime.